# TypeScript: 'super' must be called before before accessing 'this' in the constructor of a derived class

Tags: inheritance, architecture, typescript, webstorm, typescript1.8

I've seen this question passing a few times before, but I think my question is more concerning an architectural approach of this.
In TypeScript it is not possible to use the `this` keyword before calling `super` (on a class that extends from another class).
But what if you need to do something as in the example below?
(Just for clarification: I'm creating a component lifecycle for a UI library, so it feels like I really need to do something like this, and I can't seem to think of any other way of tackling this).

#### Code

What I would like to do is this:

```
class Person 
{
    public firstName: string;

    constructor()
    {
        this.scream();
    }

    protected scream(): void
    {
        console.log(this.firstName);
    }
}

class Employee extends Person
{
    public lastName: string;

    constructor(firstName: string, lastName: string)
    {
        this.lastName = lastName;
        super(firstName);
    }

    protected scream(): void
    {
        console.log(this.firstName + ' ' + this.lastName);
    }
}
```

#### Problem

The constructor of the parent class, 'Person', calls a protected method.
The child class, 'Employee', wants to use its own parameter (`this.lastName`) when overriding this protected method.
But the code above is throwing the error (in Webstorm at least):
"'super' must be called before before accessing 'this' in the constructor of a derived class"

#### Possible Solution

A) Switch `this.lastName = lastName` with the `super`call

```
class Employee extends Person
{
    ...

    constructor(firstName: string, lastName: string)
    {
        super(firstName);
        this.lastName = lastName;
    }

    ...
}
```

=> The problem here is that `this.lastName` will be `undefined` inside the `scream()` method on class 'Employee'.

B)
Use `setTimeout(callback, 0)`.
This way the `this.scream()` method will be called later.

```
class Person 
{
    ...

    constructor()
    {
        setTimeout(() => this.scream(), 0);
    }

    ...
}
```

=> But it just feels like a very ugly hack to me.

C)
Don't call `this.scream()`from inside the Person class, but call it from the consumer.

```
const employee: Employee = new Employee();
employee.scream();
```

=> But obviously this is not always what you want.

#### Question

- Am I doing a dumb thing here?
- Are there better ways to arrange my code so I don't need to do this?
- Is there some way to work around this error?

Comment: Actually a constructor shouldn't do anything else than constructing the object, i.e. giving the right values to the fields. So the best approach is NOT to call scream() inside the constructor. You can always call it from the outside and then you will never have this problem. Having the constructor executing logical code is never a good idea

Comment: By the way, option B) is really something you should never do. And option C) should be what you always want

Comment: I agree, but when creating a lifecycle I think sometimes there's no other option, no..?

Comment: @iberbeu What if the base class requires the result of an overridden method in the derived class in order to property construct the base?

Comment: @DecadeMoon If the base class requires an overriden method you are doing your base class depending on its children, which is just bad. Anyway check the solution I posted. That would be for me the way to go in such a case

Comment: See also [Call a child method from a parent class in ES6](https://stackoverflow.com/q/47820030/1048572)

Answer (score 10):

Another solution I eventually came up with, in addition to the ones provided by @iberbeu and @Nypan, is to add and intermediary `initProps()` method right before the call to `scream()`:

```
class Person 
{
    public firstName: string;

    constructor(firstName: string, props?: any)
    {
        this.firstName = firstName;
        this.initProps(props);
        this.scream();
    }

    protected initProps(props: any): void
    {
    }

    protected scream(): void
    {
        console.log(this.firstName);
    }
}

class Employee extends Person
{
    public lastName: string;

    constructor(firstName: string, lastName: string)
    {
        super(firstName, {lastName});
    }

    protected initProps(props: any): void
    {
        this.lastName = props.lastName;
    }

    protected scream(): void
    {
        console.log(this.firstName + ' ' + this.lastName);
    }
}
```

Although I think both made a strong point and I should actually be using a factory pattern instead..

Comment: Thanks! This is actually the design pattern I needed.

My setup was:
```

Answer (score 7):

**Am I doing a dumb thing here?**

Yes you are. As iberbeu said in his comment a constructor should never do anything that does not have to do with *constructing* the object. It is a case of bad practice that can lead to all sorts of unexpected behaviour.

**Are there better ways to arrange my code so I don't need to do this?**

Using the solution you provided in your **C** option is the way to go here.

**Is there some way to work around this error?**

It depends on what you actually want to do. The *normal* way of doing things is illustrated by yourself in your **C** option. If the problem you are having is related to actually instantiating complex objects you might want to look in to builder/factory patterns. But if you actually want the constructors to *do* something you are simply doing it wrong; constructors are not ment to perform actions, they are there to construct objects and nothing else.

Answer (score 3):

As I wrote in my comment and @Nypan in his answer, **you should avoid doing this**. Anyway, a possibility could be to override the method `scream` in the Child and call a new method. Take a look at the following code

```
class Person 
{
    public firstName: string;

    constructor() {
        this.scream();
    }

    protected scream(): void {
        console.log(this.firstName);
    }
}

class Employee extends Person
{
    public lastName: string;

    constructor(firstName: string, lastName: string)
    {
        super(firstName);
        this.lastName = lastName;
        this.screamOVerriden();
    }

    protected scream(): void {
        // do nothing
    }

    protected screamOverriden(): void {
        console.log(this.firstName + ' ' + this.lastName);
    }

}
```

I still don't recommend doing this but if you say you really need it and you don't care about doing it properly then this could be one solution