# Typescript inheritance call function from base class

Tags: typescript, oop, inheritance

I am using inheritance to split the logic through base and derived class.

In the following case scenario:

```
export class FirstClass{
constructor(){}

//consoleGivenMessage('dummy text');}

export class SecondClass extends FirstClass{
constructor(){
    super();
}

consoleGivenMessage(text:string){
    console.log(text);
}}
```

what is the way to call the function from the base class? Should the "`consoleGivenMessage(text:string)`" been implemented in the base class as well?

Any help is welcome

Comment: What do you mean call it from the base class? Yes you would have to define it in the base class ... I think we need more information about what you're trying to do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The short answer to your question is, you have to implement `consoleGivenMessage(text: string)` in `FirstClass` so that you can call it on instances of both `FirstClass` and `SecondClass`.

However, there is more--

Most of the time, you call an inherited method from the derived class instead of the other way round. But, you can also have a base class that depends on an *abstract* method that is implemented in a derived class.

Say, you have a class `A` that depends on a method `DoIt()` which is implemented only in derived class `B`, you would have to declare `A` as an abstract class and `DoIt()` as an abstract method; then, in `B` (which is not abstract--that is, it is concrete) you would implement the method `DoIt`().

This also means that you cannot instantiate an object of `A` because it is not complete without a full implementation of `DoIt`, but you can instantiate an object of `B`. However, you can define an object of `A`, like this: `const a: A = new B()`. And, you can call `a.DoIt()`. In this case, the implementation of `B.DoIt()` would actually be called.

This technique is used in the [Template Method design pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Template_method_pattern).

TypeScript classes, inheritance, and abstract classes are [well documented](http://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/classes.html).

Comment: that was a deep dive in to the OO inheritance, thank you for the detailed response. It was much helpful

Comment: Just avoid calling child methods from base class constructor. While it's technically possible, it's still [not recommended](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47821096/23715), since it may lead to problems related to initialization order.

Comment: @AlexChe -- Yes, of course :-)