# Pass string to constructor of abstract class

Tags: typescript, class, abstract-class, es6-class

I am looking for a way to set a name string within a class and use it in the abstract class at the constructor level, meaning not within a function. I can't open up constructor because I am using `typedi`.

[Here's the playground link.](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/?ssl=1&ssc=1&pln=12&pc=22#code/IYIwzgLgTsDGEAJYBthjAgSge24g3gLABQCZCokM8CAdsALYCmAFAJQBcCVAlrQOYlydPADFsAV1oATAKJQo2KAgC8dJgHcE8xVBYADACT4IACx5gAdPWbsAviMQAzSTP1sh5EnZIkUaDABVMCYEJgAPCCYZDBw8BCJSchtQtXZVAD4EAHJgpihs719iWGxaSARw1XUtPPYSM0UtcOsxVzkFJSA)

> Uncaught TypeError: this.name is not a function

```
abstract class Root {
    abstract name(): string
    notFoundError = new Error(`${this.name()} not found`)

}

class Use extends Root {
    name = () => 'User'
}

const x = new Use()
throw x.notFoundError
```

I am not looking for this:

```
abstract class Root {
    abstract name: string
    notFoundError = () => new Error(`${this.name} not found`)

}

class Use extends Root {
    name = 'User'
}

const x = new Use()
throw x.notFoundError()
```

Interested in `notFoundError` not being a function.

Comment: No, you can't do that, and you shouldn't - [don't call overwritten methods in a parent constructor](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47821096/1048572)! Your only way out is making `notFoundError` a getter, or making `name` static.

Answer (score 0):

One idea:

```
const Root = (name: string) => { 
    abstract class Root {
        name: string = name
        notFoundError = new Error(`${this.name} not found`)
    }
    return Root
}

class Use extends Root('User') {

}

const x = new Use()
throw x.notFoundError
```

Answer (score 0):

Rather then `name = 'User'` or `name = () => 'User'` use `name() { return 'User' }`.

```
abstract class Root {
    abstract name(): string
    notFoundError = new Error(`${this.name()} not found`)

}

class Use extends Root {
    name() { return 'User' }
}

const x = new Use()
throw x.notFoundError
```