# Javascript override class method

Tags: javascript, object, oop, bind

I'm trying to use a class from a library but want to override one of its methods. This is how the class is defined:

```
class A {
  constructor (options) {
    this._searchForm = options.searchForm 
    this._searchForm.addEventListener('submit', this.submitHandler.bind(this))
  }

  submitHandler = (e) => {
    console.log('Default')
  }
}
```

I want to override the `submitHandler` function and so this is what i did:

```
class B extends A {
  submitHandler = (e) => {
    console.log('New')
  }
}
```

However, it's still calling the old function. What am i doing wrong?

Comment: `A`'s constructor is called before `B`'s constructor, so `B` didn't have a chance to override `submitHandler` before it was bound. You could try to remove the event handler on `this._searchForm` and add your own. FWIW, `this.submitHandler.bind(this)` is unnecessary because `submitHandler` is an arrow function.

Comment: Your binding submit handler on A, you don't re-bind on B.  But if you don't want to re-bind, you might be able to do this instead. -> `addEventListener('submit', e -> this.submitHandler(e))`

Answer (score 2):

A class constructor must not call (or, in this case, bind) on overridable method (see also [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47821096/1048572)). It probably shouldn't even install event listeners - that's not the job of a constructor. But if you still want to do it, don't use class fields but method declarations:

```
class A {
  constructor (options) {
    this._searchForm = options.searchForm 
    this._searchForm.addEventListener('submit', this.submitHandler.bind(this))
  }

  submitHandler(e) {
    console.log('Default')
  }
}
class B extends A {
  submitHandler(e) {
    console.log('New')
  }
}
```

Comment: It never even occurred to me the OP was doing class fields, for some reason just though `method = (e) => {` was some fancy way of defining a method.  Of course now you've pointed it out, it's obvious it's a class field.

Comment: The class is from a package so I have no way of controlling how A is defined.

Comment: Then it's either a) the class is not designed to be subclassible, use a different way to customise it or b) it's a bug in that package. Raise an issue in the library repository.