# Using superclass methods in a superclass in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, javascript-objects

JavaScript has an OO quirk in that method calls in a superclass method will invoke subclass methods. I find I can work around this fairly easily except for constructors. The problem is that when constructing a subclass, the object is not available until `super()` is called. Any methods called by the superclass constructor that are overriden in the subclass will find an object that has not been initialized by the subclass. Here's an example:

```
class Employee {
  constructor (name, group) {
    this.name = name;
    this.setGroup(group);
  }
  setGroup (group) {
    this.group = group;
  }
}

class Manager extends Employee {
  constructor (name, group, subordinates) {
    super(name, group);
    this.subordinates = subordinates.map(name => new Employee(name, group));
  }
  setGroup (group) {
    super.setGroup(group);
    this.subordinates.forEach(sub => sub.setGroup(group));
  }
}
const mgr = new Manager('Fred', 'R&D', ['Wilma', 'Barney']);
```

This will fail in Employee.setGroup because this.subordinates has not been initialized.

One solution is to only call internal methods in the superclass constructor (e.g. _setGroup()), and provide public wrappers that can be overriden in the child. However, this is tedious as any methods called by the constructor can call other methods as well.

I came up with an alternative:

```
/**
 * Call a function that executes methods from this class, bypassing any
 * method in a subclass.
 * @param {Function} ctor - A class or Function constructor
 * @param {Object} self - An instance of the class
 * @param {Function} fn - A function to call. "this" will be set to self. Any method
 *  calls on self will ignore overriding methods in any subclass and use the
 *  ctor's methods.
 */
/* exported useClassMethods */
function useClassMethods (ctor, self, fn) {
    const subProto = Object.getPrototypeOf(self);
    // temporarily set the object prototype to this (super)class
    Object.setPrototypeOf(self, ctor.prototype);
    try {
        fn.call(self);
    } catch (error) {
        throw(error);
    } finally {
        // make sure the prototype is reset to the original value
        Object.setPrototypeOf(self, subProto);
    }
}
```

Used as follows:

```
class Employee {
  constructor (name, group) {
    useClassMethods(Employee, this, () => {
      this.name = name;
      this.setGroup(group);
    })
  }
  setGroup (group) {
    this.group = group;
  }
}
```

This seems to work, but the neutrons are pretty hot in this part of the reactor and I'd like to know if anybody else has a better solution or can pick holes in it.

Comment: `this.setGroup(group);` should be `this.group = group;` as you are in constructor. Methods will be assigned after instance is created

Comment: The example is purposely contrived to illustrate the issue.

Comment: MDN points out that using `setPrototypeOf()` can reduce object performance. There might be a way to clone an object with an edited prototype chain, apply the function, and then remerge it back into the original but it seems dicey.

Comment: After reading [this](https://mathiasbynens.be/notes/prototypes) it seems like the main penalty of using `setPrototypeOf()` is invalidating the inline caches. This is not too bad during object construction, which happens once. Afterwards, the inline caches will be reestablished by normal use. `useClassMethods()` should not be used by non-constructor methods as it may impose a severe performance penalty.

Answer (score 0):

I came up with a better solution that uses a `Proxy` object instead of manipulating the object's prototype:

```
function useClassMethods (ctor, obj, fn) {
    const classMethods = Object.create(ctor.prototype);
    const proxy = new Proxy(obj, {
        get: (target, prop) => (
            Reflect.get(target.hasOwnProperty(prop) ? target : classMethods, prop)
        ),
    })
    fn.call(proxy);
}
```

`super` works in both the subclass and superclass. The only restriction is that `fn` must not be an arrow function so that it uses the passed `this` not the lexical `this`:

```
class Employee {
  constructor (name, group) {
    useClassMethods(Employee, this, function () {
      this.name = name;
      this.setGroup(group);
    })
  }
  setGroup (group) {
    this.group = group;
  }
}
```

Comment: Proxy is still pretty slow, however...

Answer (score 0):

> JavaScript has an OO quirk in that method calls in a superclass method will invoke subclass methods.

[Yes. Don't do that in the constructor.](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3404301/1048572) (It's a problem in *all* OO languages, not just JS).

> One solution is to only call internal methods in the superclass constructor (e.g. `_setGroup()`), and provide public wrappers that can be overriden in the child.

No need for that. You can directly call the superclass method from the superclass constructor:

```
class Employee {
  constructor (name, group) {
    this.name = name;
    Employee.prototype.setGroup.call(this, group);
  }
  setGroup (group) {
    this.group = group;
  }
}
```

however this amounts to the same as just doing

```
class Employee {
  constructor (name, group) {
    this.name = name;
    this.group = group;
  }
  setGroup (group) {
    this.group = group;
  }
}
```

which is preferable - one should simply not call overrideable methods from the constructor at all.
If you absolutely feel a need to run customiseable initialisation logic on your instances that the subclass constructor cannot handle by itself, consider [this creation pattern](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47821096/1048572).

Comment: Thanks for this. The problem with your first suggestion is that calling `Employee.prototype.setGroup` can in turn call other overridable methods. My proposed solution handles that case. However, I agree that chaining is a better solution.