# JS class constructor and update function share the same implementation, using private properties. Crashes on subclasses

Tags: javascript

I'd like to be able to instantiate an object with some props, and then later update that object with the same props, and run them through the same logic.

```js
class A {
  #a = ''
  constructor(props = {}) {
    this.update(props)
  }
  update(props) {
    this.#a = props.a ?? ''
  }
}
a = new A({a: '123'})
```

I'm using private properties here, which I didn't think was a big deal, until I made a subclass:

```js
class B extends A {
  #b = ''
  update(props) {
    super.update(props)
    this.#b = props.b ?? ''
  }
}
b = new B({a: 'a', b: 'b'})
# TypeError: Cannot write private member #b to an object whose class did not declare it
```

Avoiding private properties solves it, but that's just avoiding the problem, not fixing it.

Any ideas?

Comment: [Don't call overrideable methods in the constructor](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47821096/1048572)!

Comment: @Bergi yes exactly! I agree with that statement... but the problem is: I have code to share. _How to share it!?_ How does the DRY principle survive in this case when faced with "don't call overridable methods from the constructor"?

Comment: Either extract the code that is shared between `constructor` and `update` into an external function, or at least don't call `this.update(props)` but `A.prototype.update.call(this, props)` to only assign `a`. (This is similar to what Ry did below by making `update` private). But then in `B::update` you'd have the same problem again: you'd want to call `super.update(props)`, but not from the code that is called from `B::constructor`; there `B.prototype.update.call(this, props)` wouldn't do the trick and you really need a separate helper.

Comment: Yeah I feel like this is similar to having an #update function for each class - and that's the solution I went with. It's working well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is that while `A`’s constructor is being called, you can’t use `B`’s private fields – they’re created between the construction of the `A` part of the instance and the `B` part, essentially.

One option is to only apply your own updates in the constructor, and have the superconstructor take care of the rest. (This also avoids construction time scaling with the product of the inheritance depth and the number of properties, although one hopes that wouldn’t become significant.) Not *great*, but I’m not sure if you can have all the nice parts at once.

```js
class A {
  #a = ''
  constructor(props = {}) {
    this.#update(props)
  }
  #update(props) {
    this.#a = props.a ?? ''
  }
  update(props) {
    this.#update(props)
  }
}
let a = new A({a: '123'})

class B extends A {
  #b = ''
  constructor(props = {}) {
    super(props)
    this.#update(props)
  }
  #update(props) {
    this.#b = props.b ?? ''
  }
  update(props) {
    super.update(props)
    this.#update(props)
  }
}
let b = new B({a: 'a', b: 'b'})
```

Or maybe this is better, saving some duplication at the cost of making constructors more complicated and requiring the private field defaults to be correct or callers to never forget to pass `props`:

```js
class A {
  #a = ''
  constructor(props) {
    if (props != null) this.update(props)
  }
  update(props) {
    this.#a = props.a ?? ''
  }
}
let a = new A({a: '123'})

class B extends A {
  #b = ''
  constructor(props) {
    super(null)
    if (props != null) this.update(props)
  }
  update(props) {
    super.update(props)
    this.#b = props.b ?? ''
  }
}
let b = new B({a: 'a', b: 'b'})
```

Comment: `if (props != null)` is a similar - but I think slightly improved – trick as what Alexander proposed below. Tbh I like the first solution! Constructor and update now _both point to the shared implementation_, rather than _one being the source of truth_, which means, for example, I could add custom logic to `update` that doesn't belong in the constructor. Nice. 

Comment: Having played with this, the only downside I've seen is that – in TS anyway – you have to provide defaults for all the properties (because they aren't  initialized in the constructor)

Answer (score 0):

A solution that doesn't require any changes in `A` class:

```js
class A {
  #a = ''
  constructor(props = {}) {
    this.update(props)
  }
  update(props) {
    this.#a = props.a ?? ''
  }
}
a = new A({a: '123'});

class B extends A {
  #b = ''
  
  // create a constructor for B and init 'this' with super() without arguments
  // then call update() manually with proper this (B instance)
  
  constructor(props){
    super();
    this.update(props);
  }
  update(props) {
    super.update(props);
    
    // allow this work in the A's constructor without arguments
    'b' in props && ( this.#b = props.b ?? '' );
  }
  dump(){
    console.log('#b:', this.#b);
  }
}

b = new B({a: 'a', b: 'b'});
b.dump();
```

Comment: `'b' in props` to avoid the setter there makes sense - it's fragile, though, so I think I overall like Ry's solution, but yes this is along the right path - thanks!