# Setting property in class via parent constructor doesn't set property

Tags: javascript, class, class-fields

Considering the following code

```js
class A {
    a;

    constructor() { console.log(2); this.inv(); }

    inv() { console.log(4); this.a = "a value"; }
}

class B extends A {
    b;

    constructor() { console.log(1); super(); }

    inv() {
        console.log(3);
        super.inv();
        console.log(5);
        this.b = "b value";
        console.log(this.b);
        console.log(this.constructor === B);
    }
}

const b = new B();
console.log(b.a);
console.log(b.b);
```

I get the following output:

```
1
2
3
4
5
b value
true
a value
undefined
```

I would expect `b.b` to be `b value`. How come `b.b` is `undefined`? How can I achieve what I'm trying to do?

Comment: Is it something like `b.inv.b`?

Comment: I got the output you want. But I think it is other than you want: https://jsfiddle.net/Lrakm4tf/

Comment: More of that: https://jsfiddle.net/Lrakm4tf/1/ 

Comment: The `b;` is initialised (to `undefined`) right after the `super()` call. Either remove the class field definition, or write `b = "b value";`. Or really, [never call overrideable methods from the constructor](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47821096/1048572)!

Comment: @Bergi that explains it, thanks for the answer!

Answer (score 1):

Well that is because when you're doing `const b = new B();`, you're starting off with a fresh instance of `B`, which does not have any defined value (your `b` property isn't initialized). Since you have not set a value for `b` again for this fresh instance of `B`, it will show up as `undefined`.

You are setting `b` to `b value` in `B.inv()`. So you'll need to call `b.inv()` before you print `b.b` or you can pass the `b` in the constructor. Something like

```
class B extends A {
    b;

    constructor(b) { console.log(1); super(); this.b = b; }
```

This would ensure the `b` value is assigned during object creation.

Also, as noted before, this pattern you're following isn't ideal. Your `super()` call initializes `b` to "b value" in the `b.inv()` method (which gets invoked via `super()` -> `this.inv()`) . In Class A, `this.inv()` actually calls `B.inv()` via method overriding. However, once this call is done, and we exit out of the original `super()` call in the `B` constructor, `this.b` gets defaulted to undefined. Placing an explicit `this.b = b` remedies this.

Answer (score 0):

`b;` Is setting value to `undefined` after the constructor proceeded. While Bergi comment is surely the best move (try not to nest, prefer composition over inheritance etc.) if you like it quick and dirty, you actually don't need to declare properties in JS and so you would actually get your expected output by just removing `b;`:

```
class A {
    a;

    constructor() { console.log(2); this.inv(); }

    inv() { console.log(4); this.a = "a value"; }
}

class B extends A {
    constructor() { console.log(1); super(); }

    inv() {
        console.log(3);
        super.inv();
        console.log(5);
        this.b = "b value";
        console.log(this.b);
        console.log(this.constructor === B);
    }
}

const b = new B();
console.log(b.a);
console.log(b.b);
```